# Microsoft Sync Framework Conflict Event does not fire

Tags: c#, microsoft-sync-framework

i am new to Microsoft Sync Framework and im testing with the following sample from Microsoft (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff928758.aspx):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.Synchronization;
using Microsoft.Synchronization.Data;
using Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SqlServer;
using Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SqlServerCe;

namespace ExecuteExpressSync
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SqlConnection clientConn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLCLIENT; Initial Catalog=SyncExpressDB; Trusted_Connection=Yes");

            SqlConnection serverConn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=SyncDB; Integrated Security=True");

            // create the sync orhcestrator
            SyncOrchestrator syncOrchestrator = new SyncOrchestrator();

            // set local provider of orchestrator to a sync provider associated with the 
            // ProductsScope in the SyncExpressDB express client database
            syncOrchestrator.LocalProvider = new SqlSyncProvider("ProductsScope", clientConn);


            // set the remote provider of orchestrator to a server sync provider associated with
            // the ProductsScope in the SyncDB server database
            syncOrchestrator.RemoteProvider = new SqlSyncProvider("ProductsScope", serverConn);


            // set the direction of sync session to Upload and Download
            syncOrchestrator.Direction = SyncDirectionOrder.UploadAndDownload;


            // subscribe for errors that occur when applying changes to the client
            ((SqlCeSyncProvider)syncOrchestrator.RemoteProvider).ApplyChangeFailed += new EventHandler<DbApplyChangeFailedEventArgs>(Program_ApplyChangeFailed);
            ((SqlCeSyncProvider)syncOrchestrator.LocalProvider).ApplyChangeFailed += new EventHandler<DbApplyChangeFailedEventArgs>(Program_ApplyChangeFailed);

            // 
            makeConflict(clientConn, "999");
            makeConflict(serverConn, "666");

            // execute the synchronization process
            SyncOperationStatistics syncStats = syncOrchestrator.Synchronize();

            // print statistics
            Console.WriteLine("Start Time: " + syncStats.SyncStartTime);
            Console.WriteLine("Total Changes Uploaded: " + syncStats.UploadChangesTotal);
            Console.WriteLine("Total Changes Downloaded: " + syncStats.DownloadChangesTotal);
            Console.WriteLine("Download failed: " + syncStats.DownloadChangesFailed);
            Console.WriteLine("Upload Changes failed: " + syncStats.UploadChangesFailed);
            Console.WriteLine("Complete Time: " + syncStats.SyncEndTime);
            Console.WriteLine(String.Empty);

            Console.ReadLine();

        }

        static void Program_ApplyChangeFailed(object sender, DbApplyChangeFailedEventArgs e)
        {
            // display conflict type
            Console.WriteLine(e.Conflict.Type);

            // display error message 
            Console.WriteLine(e.Error);
        }

        private static void makeConflict(SqlConnection nodeConn, String price)
        {
            int rowCount = 0;

            using (nodeConn)
            {
                SqlCommand sqlCommand = nodeConn.CreateCommand();

                sqlCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE Products SET ListPrice = " + price + " WHERE Name = 'PCClient' ";


                nodeConn.Open();
                rowCount = sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                nodeConn.Close();

            }
        }

    }
}
```

I have two SQL-Server instances (SQLCLIENT and SQLEXPRESS) on my local pc for the test environment. My problem is that the ApplyChangeFailed-Event does not fire although i create a conflict by calling makeConflict(), which performs an UPDATE for one row in the products table, both for server and client one time. The result is that either the server or the client wins, depending on the SyncDirectionOrder-property.

What i am doing wrong?

Comment: can you confirm that the updates you're making are being committed before you call synchronize? or check the _tracking table if they are actually updated?

Comment: Yes the updates will be committed before calling synchronize. The "last_change_" timestamp in the _tracking table has been also updated. It makes also no difference if i change the values manually in the Management Studio or call makeConflict(). The behavior is the same. When setting the SyncDirectionOrder to UploadAndDownload the server wins, with DownloadAndUpload the client wins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works! 
My guess that i need a dedicated server was right. 
I changed the same row on two client hosts and after synchronzing the second client the "localupdateremoteupdate" conflict has been fired.

Answer (score 1):

change this :

((SqlCeSyncProvider)syncOrchestrator

to this:

((SqlSyncProvider)syncOrchestrator

you're using the SqlSyncProvider, not the SqlCeSyncProvider

Comment: Oh sorry that was only temporary for testing. Usally i use the SQLSyncProvider.

Comment: The Code in the codebox above is not the actual state. I copied the code while testing with SQLCeSyncProvider instead of SQLSyncProvider. You only have to change SQLCeSyncProvider to SQLSyncProvider and you get my actual code. Sorry for confusion!

Answer (score 0):

To avoid further confusion here are the actual code. The problem is still existing.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.Synchronization;
using Microsoft.Synchronization.Data;
using Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SqlServer;
using Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SqlServerCe;

namespace ExecuteExpressSync
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SqlConnection clientConn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLCLIENT; Initial Catalog=SyncExpressDB; Trusted_Connection=Yes");

            SqlConnection serverConn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=SyncDB; Integrated Security=True");

            // create the sync orhcestrator
            SyncOrchestrator syncOrchestrator = new SyncOrchestrator();

            // set local provider of orchestrator to a sync provider associated with the 
            // ProductsScope in the SyncExpressDB express client database
            syncOrchestrator.LocalProvider = new SqlSyncProvider("ProductsScope", clientConn);


            // set the remote provider of orchestrator to a server sync provider associated with
            // the ProductsScope in the SyncDB server database
            syncOrchestrator.RemoteProvider = new SqlSyncProvider("ProductsScope", serverConn);


            // set the direction of sync session to Upload and Download
            syncOrchestrator.Direction = SyncDirectionOrder.UploadAndDownload;


            // subscribe for errors that occur when applying changes to the client
            ((SqlSyncProvider)syncOrchestrator.RemoteProvider).ApplyChangeFailed += new EventHandler<DbApplyChangeFailedEventArgs>(Program_ApplyChangeFailed);
            ((SqlSyncProvider)syncOrchestrator.LocalProvider).ApplyChangeFailed += new EventHandler<DbApplyChangeFailedEventArgs>(Program_ApplyChangeFailed);

            // 
            makeConflict(clientConn, "999");
            makeConflict(serverConn, "666");

            // execute the synchronization process
            SyncOperationStatistics syncStats = syncOrchestrator.Synchronize();

            // print statistics
            Console.WriteLine("Start Time: " + syncStats.SyncStartTime);
            Console.WriteLine("Total Changes Uploaded: " + syncStats.UploadChangesTotal);
            Console.WriteLine("Total Changes Downloaded: " + syncStats.DownloadChangesTotal);
            Console.WriteLine("Download failed: " + syncStats.DownloadChangesFailed);
            Console.WriteLine("Upload Changes failed: " + syncStats.UploadChangesFailed);
            Console.WriteLine("Complete Time: " + syncStats.SyncEndTime);
            Console.WriteLine(String.Empty);

            Console.ReadLine();

        }

        static void Program_ApplyChangeFailed(object sender, DbApplyChangeFailedEventArgs e)
        {
            // display conflict type
            Console.WriteLine(e.Conflict.Type);

            // display error message 
            Console.WriteLine(e.Error);
        }

        private static void makeConflict(SqlConnection nodeConn, String price)
        {
            int rowCount = 0;

            using (nodeConn)
            {
                SqlCommand sqlCommand = nodeConn.CreateCommand();

                sqlCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE Products SET ListPrice = " + price + " WHERE Name = 'PCClient' ";


                nodeConn.Open();
                rowCount = sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                nodeConn.Close();

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe i find the issue: I try to sync between one server and one client. According to the MSDN-HowTo for conflict handling (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc761628.aspx) a conflict can occur if two or more clients changed the same dataset. It seems to be that the server in this case isn´t able to change datasets too!?

This would implicate that i need a dedicated server host and two clients for my scenario. Am i right?

Comment: No. It has nothing to do with a dedicated server. The sync providers you're using are the peer-to-peer providers, there's no concept of clients or servers, just peers or replicas, source and destination.