# ApplyChangeFailed does not fired on conflict

Tags: microsoft-sync-framework

I'm trying to sync two SQL Server DBs by following Microsoft example from here [Synchronizing SQL Server and SQL Express](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff928700.aspx) and the basic sync is working for me.
Now, I tried to create a conflict by changing the same row on both DB to different values but when I run my sync process the ApplyChangeFailed is not fired.

I read this question [Microsoft Sync Framework Conflict Event does not fire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17279150/microsoft-sync-framework-conflict-event-does-not-fire) but I don't understand why when I sync client<->server configuration the framework ignore conflicts.

Here is my code, just for reference, I have a remote SQL 2008 R2 Server as the server and a local SQL 2012 Express as the client:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.Synchronization;
using Microsoft.Synchronization.Data;
using Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SqlServer;
using Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SqlServerCe;

namespace ExecuteExpressSync
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SqlConnection clientConn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=SyncExpressDB; Trusted_Connection=Yes");
            SqlConnection serverConn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=X.Y.Z.W; Initial Catalog=SyncDB; uid=sa;password=******;Integrated Security=False");

            // create the sync orhcestrator
            SyncOrchestrator syncOrchestrator = new SyncOrchestrator();

            // set local provider of orchestrator to a sync provider associated with the 
            // ProductsScope in the SyncExpressDB express client database
            syncOrchestrator.LocalProvider = new SqlSyncProvider("ProductsScope", clientConn);

            // set the remote provider of orchestrator to a server sync provider associated with
            // the ProductsScope in the SyncDB server database
            syncOrchestrator.RemoteProvider = new SqlSyncProvider("ProductsScope", serverConn);

            // set the direction of sync session to Upload and Download
            syncOrchestrator.Direction = SyncDirectionOrder.UploadAndDownload;

            // subscribe for errors that occur when applying changes to the client
            ((SqlSyncProvider)syncOrchestrator.LocalProvider).ApplyChangeFailed += new EventHandler<DbApplyChangeFailedEventArgs>(Program_ApplyChangeFailed);

            // execute the synchronization process
            SyncOperationStatistics syncStats = syncOrchestrator.Synchronize();

            // print statistics
            Console.WriteLine("Start Time: " + syncStats.SyncStartTime);
            Console.WriteLine("Total Changes Uploaded: " + syncStats.UploadChangesTotal);
            Console.WriteLine("Total Changes Downloaded: " + syncStats.DownloadChangesTotal);
            Console.WriteLine("Complete Time: " + syncStats.SyncEndTime);
            Console.WriteLine(String.Empty);
        }

        static void Program_ApplyChangeFailed(object sender, DbApplyChangeFailedEventArgs e)
        {
            // display conflict type
            Console.WriteLine(e.Conflict.Type);

            // display error message 
            Console.WriteLine(e.Error);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Subscribe to applychangefailed event on the remote provider and you'll see it fire

Answer (score 0):

As @JuneT notes this line is missing:

```
// subscribe for errors that occur when applying changes to the client
((SqlSyncProvider)syncOrchestrator.RemoteProvider).ApplyChangeFailed += new EventHandler<DbApplyChangeFailedEventArgs>(Program_ApplyChangeFailed);
```